# Quick way to switch between dodge and burn?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a shortcut for switching between doge and burn in Photoshop? When working with photo manipulations you often work with both but I've never known of a way to switch quickly between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use Dodge tool and then just press **alt** and start burning.

It is not a permanent switch. It only stays as the burn tool when you press alt.

( same thing works if you initially select burn tool, except it changes the tool to dodge when pressing alt. )

---

If you need to change the range quickly you can easily do that by **shift** right clicking the document and choose what range to use.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the Shift + Right Click trick too.

Answer (score 4):

If you disable "Use Shift Key for Tool Switch" in the General Preferences, you can simply press `O` (to go from Dodge to Burn) or `OO` (to cycle past the Sponge tool and go from Burn to Dodge). Otherwise you can keep the default behavior and use `Shift-O` and `Shift-O Shift-O` respectively.

For an even quicker Dodge and Burn switching technique, add a new layer in Overlay mode and fill with 50% gray. Set your colors to the defaults (`D`) and use the Brush tool at an opacity of about 10% in Overlay mode on your new layer. You can toggle between Dodge (white brush) and Burn (black brush) by pressing `X`.

Comment: +2 if I could for alternative technique. Thank you.

Comment: I love tricks like that. :)